# laravel blade template engine content displayed outside end html tag

Tags: templates, laravel, view

I am very new to laravel frame work, I am using laravel 4.2, now i have a problem with my blade template engine. 
    In my laravel admin panel After user login one dashboard page will display. This       page is working fine.This page consists of master.header.php (which is my header) and dashboard page which is my left menu.

**Blade code as follows**

```
<pre>
   below is my dashboard page code 
   @extends('includes.header')
   @section('head')

   @parent   
   <title>DashBoard</title>
   @stop

   @section('content')
   LEFT MENU COMES HERE 
   @stop
</pre>
   <pre>Now in my left menu different links are there.
```

So i want to inlcude header.blade.php and dashboard.blade.php in each link page.

**Left menu page code as follows**

```
<pre>
    page name is : Employee.blade.php
    @extends('usercp.dashboard')
    @section('head')
    @stop
    @section('content')
    hi this is my one of left menu section
</pre>
    **OUT PUT**
<pre>

But when i click on the left menu link the content is displaying (hi this is my one of left menu section) at the header. 
When i see the source of Employee.blade.php the left menu is out side </html> tag.
Not in body tag. 
Can any one please help me in this regard.

</pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

A few thoughts on your code:

- In your left menu page the `@section('content')` is not closed, add a
  `@stop`
- The `@extends` command has to be the first line in your blade
  template, with no html/whitespaces before it.
- If you want to include another blade template (e.g. your header), use
  `@include('partials.header')`. By extending another template you can
  override the sections of your parent template, which is not
  what you want for your header, I'd guess.